# Not able to populate auto complete result in HTML input field

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to do an autocomplete callback function, I am able to retreive data from the database but not able to populate the list to input box. I am using servlets.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="userId">Enter Your Name:</label>
        <input id="userId">
    </div>
    <strong id="selected"></strong>
    <strong>Ajax Response</strong>:
    <div i="ajaxGetUserServletResponse" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
</body>
</html>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#userId").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "GetAutoCompResp",
                dataType: "json",
                method: "post",
                data: {
                    userId: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var value = ui.item.label;
            $("#ajaxGetUserServletResponse").text(value);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

[Please see the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJLou.png)

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is the exact problem you are having?

Comment: I am not able to populate values in UI like dropdown

Comment: Can't help you with your specific code as you are running a custom (only you can access that URL) but I can provide a basic implementation of AutoComplete https://jsfiddle.net/skelly/9R4cV/

Comment: There’s a typo: `<div i="ajaxGetUser…` should be `<div id="ajaxGetUser…`. This element is also missing a closing-tag.

Comment: Hi  insertusernamehere, that not be the issue, that is second purpose, but initially I want to populate the list in User Interface